# Selenium2 / WebDriver: How to click an <i> element in an <a> element?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java

I got stuck for the below code.it has an edit icon for which code are follows:

```
<a href="#tradeModal" id="tradeModalEdit" data-toggle="modal" class="pull-right" style="margin-left: 12px;" title="Edit trade" onclick="return populateTradeTicketSectionEdit(); ClearTradeModal();"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
```

This is the one for which i coded in selenium :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='#tradeModal'and contains(@id,'tradeModalEdit')]/i[@class='icon-edit']")).click();
```

when i click on save by using below code:

```
WebElement saveEditTrade = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='#' and contains(@onclick,'return SaveTradeDetails();')]")); //code for saving the details in edit trade pop up//
saveEditTrade.click();
```

this works fine but point is when i am clicking on consecutive window edit icon like below:

```
<a href="#feeModal" data-toggle="modal" class="pull-right" style="margin-left: 12px;" title="Edit fee" onclick="  return clearFeeModal();"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
```

selenium code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='#feeModal'and contains(@onclick,'clearFeeModal();')]/i[@class='icon-edit']")).click();//code for saving the details in Edit Fee pop up
```

it has other input fields dats okies but my point is execution fails bcuz its showing element is not visible for last edit code that i posted just above line.i can see when data are populating for saving for 1st code at the same time 2nd edit code pops up eventhough i put implicit wait commands or i tried with expected conditions wait.

Please advise.

Comment: Did you try using xcode only for the <i> or the <a> rather than nested xcode? Try one element at a time and see if it works!

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you code your locator like this?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a/i[@class='icon-edit']")).click();
```

Seems like it would have still worked and would have been simpler.